# need to force index for the select be able to works faster?

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join

I have a big select and when I use explain it shows:

[image]
I need to use `force index` to use `(user)` as an index (key) on pp table.

After force index, it will remove the user (key) in `pp2` table. so I need to use force index `(user)` on `pp2` too.

After forcing index on `pp` and `pp2` the table `p` will use `primary` as index automatically and all will works fine.

**My question here is, what is the problem? why mysql is not using the possible_keys `user` as key in pp table?**

why after I force `pp` to use `user` key it will mess up with the key on `pp2`? adding key = null on it.
why after forcing `pp` and `pp2` using user as key, the table p will use primary as key and all will works fine?

sql:

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2, 

linked.id as shared_id, linked.titulo as shared_titulo, linked.user as shared_user_id, c2.user as shared_nick, linked.foto as shared_foto, pp2.foto as shared_perfil,
count(DISTINCT share_count.id) as shares_count

from posts p 

join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp force index (user) on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = 1

left join posts linked on linked.id = p.post_share
left join cadastro c2 on linked.user=c2.id
left join profile_picture pp2 force index (user) on linked.user = pp2.user
left join posts share_count on share_count.post_share = p.id and share_count.delete=0

where (p.user in (select following from following where user =1 and block=0) or p.user=1) and p.delete=0
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit 15
```

the profile picture:

```
CREATE TABLE `profile_picture` (
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

thanks.

Comment: Is `posts.user` also `UNSIGNED`?  If there are really only 5 rows in `pp`, then a table scan is as fast as using an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for improve performance you could also for avoid the IN  clause and use an inner join for this eg: (i hope)

```
  select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2, 

  linked.id as shared_id, linked.titulo as shared_titulo, linked.user as shared_user_id, c2.user as shared_nick, linked.foto as shared_foto, pp2.foto as shared_perfil,
  count(DISTINCT share_count.id) as shares_count

  from posts p 

  join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
  left join profile_picture pp force index (user) on p.user = pp.user
  left join likes on likes.post = p.id
  left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
  left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = 1

  left join posts linked on linked.id = p.post_share
  left join cadastro c2 on linked.user=c2.id
  left join profile_picture pp2 force index (user) on linked.user = pp2.user
  left join posts share_count on share_count.post_share = p.id and share_count.delete=0

  inner join following f on (f.following = p.user and f.user=1 and f.block = 0 and p.delete=0)  
      OR  ( p.user=1 and p.delete =0)

  group by p.id
  order by p.id desc limit 15
```

and looking to your pp table where you have an unique index in user   you could try change this to pk condition in create

```
  CREATE TABLE `profile_picture` (
    `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `foto` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY   (`user`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'll change it! and do you know why mysql is not using my index on pp table?

Comment: could be this is related  to missing a primary key  .. answer  updated  with a suggestion  .. (hope is useful)

Comment: Oh, it works! I changed the unique key to primary and now I don't need to force index anymore.

Comment: yeah! the primary key is really necessary, it speeds up my query x5. thanks.